# Trying to bind datatable with listbox...something wrong

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, datatable, this

Please help...what am I doing wrong here? Trying to bind listbox to datatable. After debugging, i see data rows in the table but some how it is not binding to listbox.

FYI. _this is the name of my current window...

```
            <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=MainCategoriesTable}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" x:Name="lbMainCategories">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=main_category_name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="grpMainCategory" x:Name="rdbEnableDisable" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Width="30" Background="Transparent" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Below is the property trying to bind with...

```
    public DataTable MainCategoriesTable
    {
        get { return _dtMainCategory; }
        set { _dtMainCategory = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the control named '_this'?  Would you not want to bind to something in the DataContext instead?

Comment: I tried DataContext as well. It didn't work too.

_this is my current window name like:

        <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Window3" Height="1000" Width="1200"
    x:Name="_this">
To be honest. I tried that exact code couple of days back and it worked. I don't know what I made changes or what changed and now it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

For XAML to set the data context tocode behind this is what works for me

```
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

in code behind

```
  this.DataContext = this;
```

But I used _this like you have used it successfully.

Set Presentation.Trace = High in the all XAML binding.  That is not the exact syntax but if you start with Presentation it should be obvious.

Why no binding on label.

main_category_name is a public property?  I notice it is in lower case.

Comment: well main_category_name is the column name in DataTable.

Comment: if radio button would have worked, then i would try label too. But i was stuck on radio button.

Comment: May be are right to use DataContext. But I am pretty confident that I don't need to use DataContext. So, just to give your idea a shot I tried DataContext and it didn't work too.. :(

Comment: BUT when I use dependecyProperty to bind my DataTable and IT WORKED!

Comment: It worked in both cases like DataContext="{Binding Element=_local}" and ItemSource="{Binding Path="AllMainCategoriesTable"}

Comment: I don't know do I really need to use DependencyProperty for every Binding??? Any idea????

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable` works like a dictionary, not like an object. It doesn't expose your columns as properties, but each `DataRow` exposes an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/146h6tk5.aspx) that can be used to get the cell value. Therefore, you need to use indexer syntax:

```
<RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=[main_category_name]}" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="grpMainCategory" x:Name="rdbEnableDisable" />
```

**UPDATE**

Another thing that bothers me is that your `MainCategoriesTable` property doesn't notify about changes. If it's changed after all `Bindings` have been initialized, it won't work (while `DependencyProperty` will, because it always notifies about changes). To make it work, your context class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and your property must look like this:

```
public DataTable MainCategoriesTable
{
    get { return _dtMainCategory; }
    set
    {
      if(value == _dtMainCategory)
      {
        return;
      }

      _dtMainCategory = value;
      var h = this.PropertyChanged;
      if(h != null)
      {
        h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MainCategoriesTable"));
      }
    }
}
```